# AutoLayout constraints conflict after strings translation

Tags: ios

On a well working application, I just did the strings translation in code and storyboard and then, I get an 'Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints' error.

The error is:

```
    Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
(
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d5408d0 V:[UIView:0x1d540c40(0)]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d540910 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x1d540c40]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1d541100 )>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d540fd0 V:[UILabel:0x1d541040(21)]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d5407d0 V:[UIView:0x1d540c40]-(20)-[UILabel:0x1d541040]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d540710 V:[LTSelectView:0x1d542210]-(360)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1d541100 )>",
 "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1d5928b0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x1d541100(416)]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d540690 V:[UILabel:0x1d541040]-(19)-[LTSelectView:0x1d542210]>"
 )

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d540fd0 V:[UILabel:0x1d541040(21)]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Does the translation somewhere responsible of it?

I read few posts on this subject but reasons are really not easy to understand for me.

So my objects are:

UILabel:
Height equals 21
Width equals: 220
Top space to top Layout: 17
Align center X to: superview
Bottom space to Selectview: 22

LTSelectView:
Width equals to: 160
Height equals to: 30
Align center X to: superview
Top space to UILabel: 22
Bottom space to UIButton: 67

UIButton:
Width equals to: 100
Height equals to: 30
Top space to SelectView: 67
Align center to: superview

And in fact I can see the UILabel, the UIButton but not the LTSelectView. So the problem is certainly here.
I trie to use the obj_exception_throw but I did get anything.

After other tests, I only the problem on iOS6. Things go well on iOS7.

Comment: Did you add the constraints in code? There is this `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint` which looks like you forgot to set the `translatesAutoresizingMasksToContraints` to NO.

Comment: No I didn't add any constraints in code and in doubt, I add this line in my viewDidLoad method and the result is a pure nightmare! Nothing is in a right location anymore.

Comment: Then my answer is: Your constraints aren't correct.

Answer (score 0):

One of your label has too many vertical constraints and they can not be satisfied at the same time.

Change the priority of some constraints or rebuild them.

Comment: I updated my post to explain what are my object and constraints. Don't see what can I remove...